# String of boolean values to an array?

Tags: java

I created the code below to print out all of the values of a string to 'true' or 'false'.  I would like to fill an array with all the printed values "True true false true...."  Right now when I print out the values of the String str if it is not in the loop I only get the first value of the first character.

```
    // First find out how many words and store in numWords
    // Use "isDelim()" to determine delimiters versus words
    //
    // Create wordArr big enough to hold numWords Strings
    // Fill up wordArr with words found in "phrase" parameter
    public void Parse(String phrase) {
      int len = phrase.length(); 
      String str = null;

      int isTrueCount = 0;
      int isFalseCount = 0;

      for (int i = 0; i < (len); i++) { 
        str = String.valueOf(!isDelim(phrase.charAt(i)));
        System.out.println(str);

        if (str == "true") {
          isTrueCount++;
        } else {
          isFalseCount++;
        }
      }
      System.out.println(isTrueCount);
      System.out.println(isFalseCount);
    }
```

Length of len is any arbitrary string/text file/keyboard input.  I am hoping to use the true and false values within an array to pick out the true number of words from delims.

Comment: Please give us the starting values of len and phrase.

Comment: You're over-writing the String with each iteration of the loop. Perhaps you want to do `str += String.valueOf(foo) + " ";`.  Better still, don't create a String at all, but add the results into an `ArrayList<Boolean>`.

Comment: Maybe you can explain *what* you are trying to do.  Forget about the algorithms and the loops.  Just what is the goal?  You have a string, and what do you want to do?  Count delimiters?  Count characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use Strings for this as it adds unnecessary complexity. Simply increment your variable if the statement is true:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++) {
     if (!isDelim(phrase.charAt(i))) {
        isTrue++;
     } else {
        isFalse++;
     }
  }
```